# Need to get a statement covered in test class

Tags: community

I want to get the following statement covered:

```
contactId= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get(UTIL_CONSTANTS.CONSTANT1);
```

I need to cover it in the test class where

```
public static final String  CONSTANT1 = 'contactparm';
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following which will set the desired Page as the current page using [setCurrentPage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setCurrentPage) and then set a parameter on that page.

The last line in the code gives an example of how you would test the `contactId`.

```
   PageReference pr = Page.myPage;
   Test.setCurrentPage(pr);
   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put(CONSTANT1, idVariable);
   System.assertEquals(idVariable, pageController.contactId);
```